# Order by on a nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

Is their a way to order this by the `Time` column? I am not sure how to do this. The time is the schedule and I just need it to go from the morning to the evening.

Can I just nest another select statement and use that?

Thank you.

```
SELECT
    DoseLevel,
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    DOB,
    EMPLID,
    Time,
    (   
        SELECT v.ColorCode  
        FROM ABCDocumentation cd1   
        LEFT JOIN ABCDocumentation cd2ON cd1.ABCDocumentationID = cd2.PairID    
        LEFT JOIN Medicine v ON v.MedicineID = cd1.MedicineID   
        LEFT JOIN Manufacturers mfg ON v.MFG_Seq = mfg.MFG_Seq  
        WHERE cd2.ABCDocumentationID = dt.ABCDocumentationID    
    ) AS ParentColorCode,   
    (   
        SELECT mfg.Description  
        FROM ABCDocumentation cd1   
        LEFT JOIN ABCDocumentation cd2 ON cd1.ABCDocumentationID = cd2.PairID   
        LEFT JOIN Medicine v ON v.MedicineID = cd1.MedicineID   
        LEFT JOIN Manufacturers mfg ON v.MFG_Seq = mfg.MFG_Seq  
        WHERE cd2.ABCDocumentationID = dt.ABCDocumentationID
    ) AS ParentManuDesc
FROM
(
    SELECT
        cd.DoseLevel,
        e.LastName,
        e.FirstName,
        e.DOB,
        cvse.EMPLID,
        cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID,
        cd.ABCDocumentationID,
        cvss.Time,
        cd.ModifyDate AS 'StartTime'
    FROM ABCAdminSchedule cvs
    LEFT JOIN ABCAdminScheduleSlots cvss ON cvs.AdminScheduleID = cvss.AdminScheduleID
    LEFT JOIN ABCAdminScheduleSlotsEmployee cvse ON cvss.AdminScheduleSlotsID = cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsID
    LEFT JOIN ABCDocumentation cd ON cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID = cd.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN Employee e ON cvse.EmplID = e.EMPLID
    WHERE CAST(TIME AS Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND CampusID = '06'
    AND cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID IS NOT NULL
) dt
```

Comment: add `order by Time`?

Comment: You are doing a lot here, I would suggest looking up CTE or use temp tables to insert data into first, then run some extra logic off that.  Will probably help performance as well as readability

Comment: And watch out for `CAST(TIME AS Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)` as soon as you start calling functions on your columns in the where clause it becomes un-sargable and potentially suffers a performance hit.

Comment: Order By after dt worked

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no need for the derived table `dt`, as you are not doing any further processing.

Secondly, you can combine the two correlated subqueries into one with an `APPLY`.

Thirdly, conversions on columns can cause performance issues, so you can change the date check to a half-open interval, converting just `GETDATE()`.

Finally you can add at the end an `ORDER BY` clause to sort.

```sql
SELECT
    cd.DoseLevel,
    e.LastName,
    e.FirstName,
    e.DOB,
    cvse.EMPLID,
    cvss.Time,
    Parent.ColorCode,
    Parent.Description

FROM ABCAdminSchedule cvs
    LEFT JOIN ABCAdminScheduleSlots cvss ON cvs.AdminScheduleID = cvss.AdminScheduleID
    LEFT JOIN ABCAdminScheduleSlotsEmployee cvse ON cvss.AdminScheduleSlotsID = cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsID
    LEFT JOIN ABCDocumentation cd ON cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID = cd.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN Employee e ON cvse.EmplID = e.EMPLID

    OUTER APPLY
    (   
        SELECT v.ColorCode, mfg.Description
        FROM ABCDocumentation cd1   
        LEFT JOIN ABCDocumentation cd2ON cd1.ABCDocumentationID = cd2.PairID    
        LEFT JOIN Medicine v ON v.MedicineID = cd1.MedicineID   
        LEFT JOIN Manufacturers mfg ON v.MFG_Seq = mfg.MFG_Seq  
        WHERE cd2.ABCDocumentationID = dt.ABCDocumentationID    
    ) AS Parent 

    WHERE TIME >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND TIME < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    AND CampusID = '06'
    AND cvse.AdminScheduleSlotsEmployeeID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TIME
```

Answer (score -2):

please

```
declare @tm table (id int identity, timee time(7))
insert into @tm (timee) values ('01:05:45'),
                           ('10:15:18'),
                           ('14:18:59'),
                           ('09:15:10'),
                           ('18:19:21'),
                           ('21:05:17')
```

this is a default

`select * from @tm order by id`

this is a, what do you need

```
select tm.*,
   iif(tm.part_time = 1, 'morning', 'evening') m_e from (select 
        case
            when timee between '09:00:00' and '19:00:00' then 1 
            else 2 end part_time, 
            * 
         from  @tm) tm 
    order by part_time, timee
```

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with the question?

Comment: ^^^ what he said